# Breaking ties for categorizing in SAS

Tags: sas

I’m trying to categorize customers, and one of the columns I need to make is a customer’s primary product with ties broken by the amount the customer spent. Here's an example of what the ties in my raw data look like:

```
|Customer #|Product|Spend|
|Customer 1|   A   |800  |
|Customer 1|   B   |900  |
|Customer 2|   C   |100  |
|Customer 2|   C   |550  |
|Customer 2|   B   |200  |
|Customer 2|   B   |300  |
```

Customers 1 and 2 both have ties in the number of times they purchased a product, so for the Primary Product field I need to make, I need to use the amount the customers spent on each product to break the ties. Customer 1 spend more on ProdB than on ProdA, some Customer 1's Primary Product should be B.

So I need to make something like this:

```
| Customer #|Prod A |Prod B|Prod C|Primary Product|
| Customer 1|   1   |   1  |   0  |   B           |
| Customer 2|   0   |   2  |   2  |   C           |
```

I have entries for each customer’s transactions, showing what products they bought and how much they paid for, as well as a Customer ID number unique to each customer.
Summing up the number of times a customer buys a product is no problem, but I don't know how to write the code to break the tie.
How do I write code to choose a customer’s primary product that will break ties based on the amount the customer spent?

Comment: Sort by your spend within your primary key and take the first. So you want the primary sort to by number of what?.  Observations? Or is there some quantity variable in addition the cost?  Please show the structure of the raw data you will use as the basis for the decision.

Comment: @Tom I edited my post to make it more clear - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Broken down into smaller steps. In the future please include whatever you've tried in your questions.

```
data have;
infile cards delimiter='|' dsd truncover;
length customerID $10.;
input customerID $ product  $ Spend;
cards;
Customer 1|   A   |800  |
Customer 1|   B   |900  |
Customer 2|   C   |100  |
Customer 2|   C   |550  |
Customer 2|   B   |200  |
Customer 2|   B   |300  |
;;;;
run;

*summarize to totals first;
proc means data=have nway noprint ;
class customerID product;
var SPEND;
output out=product_total sum=total_spend N=COUNT;
run;

*sort as needed;
proc sort data=product_total;
by customerID descending COUNT descending total_spend;
run;

*identify the primary product;
data want_long;
set product_total;
by customerID;
retain primary_product;
if first.customerID then primary_product=product;
run;

*sort for order after transpose;
proc sort data=want_long;
by customerID primary_PRODUCT PRODUCT;
run;

*transpose to desired structure;
proc transpose data=want_long out=want_wide prefix=PROD_;
by customerID primary_Product;
id product;
var Count;
run;
```